# Hide HTML element via GTM: Javascript vs CSS, which is faster?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to hide an HTML element using Google Tag Manager, but I am wondering which method is faster, JavaScript or CSS.

I always assumed that inserting CSS itself, will hide the HTML element faster than using JavaScript to insert some inline CSS. However, I tested both and it feels that JavaScript actually hides element faster. However, I don't have numbers that prove my point. What's the logic behind?

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector(".hello-world").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

**CSS**:

```
<style>
  .hello-world{
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS is by far the best way to apply styling to any element on page load. This is because CSS can be applied after the stylesheet loads, which is generally before the DOM has been rendered, so you don't get a flicker of content appearing and disappearing.

This is in contrast to JS, which has to wait until the DOM has loaded which means the element will be visible before it's suddenly hidden (excepting cached scripts etc). This issue is known as a ['Flash of Unstyled Content'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), or FOUC.

As a side note, CSS is hardware accelerated, so if you have any animation you'd like to show, it's also good practice to try and create it using only CSS/SVG instead of JS.